# How to getting the page number or correct posi in an Android ScrollView

Tags: android, position, scrollview

I have a LinearLayout containing two ImageViews. The LinearLayout is inside the ScrollView.
When I scroll the screen I would like to know the exact position of the two ImageViews relative to scroll. The getScrollY() doesn't work correctly because the ImageViews continues scrolling after action_up and the value in getScrollY isn't updated in this case. I have this information to disable or enable other elements on screen.

Answer (score 0):

If your 2 views are the same/similar then add them to a ListView, then you can set an OnScrollListener which will tell you when the view is scrolled and the index of the visible item.